# how to diagnose blocked service responses

Tags: ubuntu, networking, docker, server

i have a few services running a little server.  if i run one of the arbitrary services manually, i can very clearly see the request-response lifecycle complete successfully after client request.  however, the client *never actually* receives the response.  i've observed this behavior both in browser and with curl.  it's as though my system is permitting inbound communication, but not outbound.

my server is an ubuntu server, recently updated.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
$ uname -r
3.13.0-37-generic
```

some services are run thru docker, some are just running on the (cloud) metal.  whether the service is thru docker or on the metal(ish) appears to be irrelevant--the failure mode occurs in both modalities. i've also tried running my server as a privileged user, with no change.

thus far, i've tested a basic static file server (node/express) & a github webhook utility (node/hapi) both getting requests, responding, yet still leaving clients in the dark.

- ufw is disabled
- iptable dump can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/10e93d418375ac03838bac8061b4bd24)

**what can i do to get my responses down the wire to my clients?**

Comment: your iptables dump only includes some of your rules. Run `iptables-save` to get a true full list of all iptables rules. Can you include any of your test cases and their results that you have drawn on to conclude that the request-response lifecycle is completing successfully? Another tool to help diagnosing this issue would be to look at the iptables counters. Run `iptables` commands with the `-v` option, or `iptables -c`. If you run those in succession, any rules that are triggered between those two runs should have their count increase.

Comment: thanks @programmerq, i'll look into your remarks shortly and report back!